# How to create a list of numbers following the natural number sequence according to their length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want the list of numbers as:

```
n = int(input("Enter count")

if n=1 , lst =["1"]
if n=2, lst=["1","2"]
if n=3, lst =["1","2","3"]
```

The list should contain the elements as strings, not integers.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use range to create the numbers and since you want strings, you can afterwards map them to strings:

```
n = int(input("Enter count")
list(map(str, range(1, n+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and range..

```
n = int(input('Enter count:')
lst = list(map(str, list(range(1,n+1))))
```

Comment: The elements should be string

Answer (score 0):

You could use for-loop, and each iteration append `i+1` to a list, Since `for-loop` start from index 0:

```py
n = int(input("n:")) #5
l = []
for i in range(n):
    l.append(str(i+1))
print(l) #['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

With list comprehension:

```py
print([str(i+1) for i in range(n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is efficient

```
n = int(input("Enter count:"))
lst = [str(x) for x in range(1,n+1)]
```